# NULL response from JMS Serializer when enabling handler

Tags: symfony, serialization, null, jmsserializerbundle

(Symfony + JMS Serializer)

I have the following service:

```
my_serializer:
        class: MySerializer
        tags:
            - { name: jms_serializer.handler, type: MyClass, direction: serialization, format: json, method: serializeMyClassToJson }
```

The service class contains just one method:

```
public function serializeMyClassToJson(
    JsonSerializationVisitor $visitor,
    MyClass $myObject,
    array $type,
    Context $context
) {
    return array(
        'id' => $myObject->getId()
         // .. and so on
    );
}
```

I get a NULL result when calling `serialize()` on any object of this class when my handler is enabled (ie. registered in JMS Serializer - if I remove it, everything works fine):

```
$this->container->get('jms_serializer')->serialize($myObject, 'json'); // null
```

A few things to notice:

1. My serialization method is called and I am sure I return the proper array from it (obviously, I tested with several dummy arrays - but the result is the same).
2. Strangely, the serialization works when `MyClass` is part of a different Doctrine managed entity and I serialize that entity (`MySecondClass` has a `OneToOne` relation to `MyClass`):

   ```
   [...]->serialize($mySecondObject, 'json'); // includes the correct JSON result for $myObject
   [...]->serialize($mySecondObject->getMyObject(), 'json'); // null
   ```
3. I didn't define any annotations for the properties in MyClass.

So, probably I'm missing some annotations or callbacks for my handler?

Answer (score 2):

A workaround (though not an answer for my question) seems to be the following adjustment to my handler callback:

```
public function serializeMyClassToJson(
    JsonSerializationVisitor $visitor,
    MyClass $myObject,
    array $type,
    Context $context
) {
    $result = array(
        'id' => $myObject->getId()
         // .. and so on
    );

    // Populate the root element if it's NULL
    // (with this change, the JSON output seems to be correct)
    if ($visitor->getRoot() === null) {
        $visitor->setRoot($result);
    }

    return $result;
}
```